# How to use $urlRouterProvider.rule

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

OK, this could be a UI-Router bug, or could just be my fault. I posted a question on Git https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2342, no response yet , much appriciate if anyone could help here

if I do somehing like:

```
angular.module('myapp', [ 'ui.router' ])

    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/state1");

        $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
            return "/state2";
        });

        $stateProvider
            .state('state1', {
                url: "/state1",
                views: {
                    "mainview": { template: "state1.html" }
                }
            })
            .state('state2', {
                url: "/state2",
                views: {
                    "mainview": { template: "state2.html" }
                }
            });
    })

    .controller('AppCtrl', AppCtrl);

    function AppCtrl(){
    }
```

Address bar is changed but `state2.html` is not loaded, there is only a blank page without throwing any errors

Thanks very much for any possible solutions.

Comment: Could you Please change `mainview` in to your `$stateProvider` as `state1` also `state2` .This might be help you soo...

Comment: Hi Sakthi, thanks for your answer. Sorry that I couldn't follow your, and could you please explain what exactly do you mean change mainview into $stateProvider? Like having a code example? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Think about the **`.rule`** as an AOP filter. It is just an aspect, which

- is executed **always**, when url changes,
- and could adjust that url.

In comparison with otherwise, which is treated as a "last url resolution handler".

So, the best use, as described in the doc, is to introduce a case-insensitive url support:

#### [rule(rule)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider)

> Defines rules that are used by $urlRouterProvider to find matches for
>   specific URLs.
>
> - **`rule`**  *`object`*  Handler function that takes $injector and $location services as arguments. You can use them to return a valid
>     path as a string.
>
> example:
>
> ```
> var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router.router']);
>
> app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider) {
>   // Here's an example of how you might allow case insensitive urls
>   $urlRouterProvider.rule(function ($injector, $location) {
>     var path = $location.path(),
>         normalized = path.toLowerCase();
>
>     if (path !== normalized) {
>       return normalized;
>     }
>   });
> });
> ```

There is an [example with above stuff](http://plnkr.co/edit/4XMBfuvarfakjvX85w94?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Radim, thanks for your answer. From my understanding, as long as the callback function returns an valid url path, the state associated with the path  should be loaded, just as described in doc. And since it is designed for as a customer url handler, I agree that, it could be used for case-insensitive url support, as your suggested, but only used for this purpose, it could be anything goes into the function.